# Does any SSL (EV, OV, DV) require a dedicated IP?

Tags: ssl, ip, dedicated

Just trying to get my head around requirements, from what I can see EV, OV and DV do not require a dedicated IP? I was just wondering if someone could clarify and enlighten?

Comment: Are you talking about SSL *certificates*?

Comment: Yes SSL certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificates you mention are issued for one or multiple domain names. There is no technical restriction which IP address is associated with these domain names. This means there is no technical requirement to use these certificates together with a dedicated IP address. But note that if you want to share the same IP address between different certificates (and thus different domains) the client and server need to support Server Name Indication (SNI) in the TLS handshake. Modern clients (at least the browsers) and servers usually do this but you better check if you need to rely on specific clients.